# Tensor product of two chain homotopic maps are again chain homotopic

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $C$, $C'$, $D$, $D'$ be chain complexes, $f$, $f'\colon C\to C'$ and $g$, $g'\colon D \to D'$ two pairs of homotopic chain maps. How to show $f \otimes g$ and $f' \otimes g' \colon C\otimes D\to C'\otimes D'$ are homotopic? I have tried many formulas for such a homotopy, but none of them worked.

Comment: First do the case $g = g' = 1_{D'}$, so show that $f \otimes 1_{D'} \simeq f' \otimes 1_{D'}$ (or even better $(f-f') \otimes 1_{D'} \simeq 0$), then use the formula $f \otimes g = (f \otimes 1_{D'}) \circ (1_{C} \otimes g)$ together with the fact that compositions of homotopic maps are homotopic. From there it should be easy to figure out the formula for the homotopy (if you really need it).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that avoids some computations (really they're hidden under the hood and I'm pretty sure that if you followed the advice given in t.b.'s comment you would find the same thing). I'm implicitly using the enriched $\operatorname{Hom}(C,D)$ functor of chain complex, where a cycle in degree zero is a chain map $C \to D$, and a boundary of degree zero is a nullhomotopic chain map.

Let $F = f - f'$ and $G = g - g'$. Then both $F$ and $G$ are null homotopic, i.e. there exist homotopies $h$ and $k$ such that $F = \partial(h)$ and $G = \partial(k)$ (where $\partial(h) = dh + hd$). We also know that $f$, $f'$, $g$, and $g'$ are chain maps, i.e. $\partial(f) = \partial(f') = 0$ and $\partial(g) = \partial(g') = 0$. What we want to do is express $f \otimes g - f' \otimes g'$ as the boundary of some homotopy. So let's write:
$$\begin{align}
f \otimes g - f' \otimes g'
& = f \otimes g - f' \otimes g + f' \otimes g - f' \otimes g' \\
& = F \otimes g + f' \otimes G \\
& = \partial(h) \otimes g + f' \otimes \partial(k) \\
& = \partial(h \otimes g + f' \otimes k)
\end{align}$$
Where I used the fact that $\partial(h \otimes g) = \partial(h) \otimes g - h \otimes \partial(g)$ and the second term is zero.

So to conclude, if $h$ is the homotopy between $f$ and $f'$, and $k$ is the homotopy between $g$ and $g'$, the homotopy between $f \otimes g$ and $f' \otimes g'$ is given by
$$c \otimes d \mapsto h(c) \otimes g(d) + (-1)^{|c|} f'(c) \otimes k(d),$$
where the sign comes from the Koszul rule of signs
$$(f' \otimes k)(c \otimes d) = (-1)^{|k| \cdot |c|} f'(c) \otimes k(d) = (-1)^{|c|} f'(c) \otimes k(d).$$